# corrupted bootable usb stick

Tags: 14.04

I was making a bootable usb(using unetbootin) stick for kali-linux but the process was interupted before it finished and now the usb stick is read-only and can neither format it nor change the permision. your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First wipe away the MBR with dd.  (Make SURE you know which device it is, as this will destroy anything on there.  If you do this to your harddrive you're finished.)

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=2
```

Then you should be able to unmount it, unplug it, plug it back in, and reformat it with ubuntu.  Or do it at the command line with fdisk.